# BufferedReader and enumerating multiple lines in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, enumeration, owl, ontology

I am in the process of making a java application that reads through a `.ttl` file line by line and creates a `graphml` file to represent the ontology.

I am having some trouble figuring out how to enumerate a certain section.

I am using `BufferedReader` to read each line.

For example, I have the following:

```
else if (line.contains("owl:oneOf")){

    // insert code to enumerate list contained in ( )

}
```

And this is what the .ttl looks like for oneOf:

```
    owl:oneOf  (GUIFlow:ExactlyOne
                GUIFlow:OneOrMore
                GUIFlow:ZeroOrMore
                GUIFlow:ZeroOrOne )
```

I need to return those 4 objects as one list, to be used as part of a graphical representation of an ontology.

Comment: You'd parse the line and interpret the line content depending on the current state, i.e. if you previously encountered `owl:oneOf (` you know you have the element `owl:oneOf` and the start of a list, so what follows are list elements until you encounter the corresponding `)`.

Comment: I would recommend not writing a Turtle parser from scratch. There are various APIs that already allow parsing, many of them Open Source, so you can use them directly or extend/reuse the code to fit your application. Sesame and Jena, mentioned in @david-soroko's answer, are two good starting points.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have some kind of loop going through the file. Here are some ideas:

**1)** Introduce a "state" into the loop so that upon reading the next line it will know that it's actually inside the oneOf list. A dynamic array to store the list can serve as the state. You create the list when encountering the `(`, and you send the list wherever it is needed when encountering the `)` and then delete the list after that. A complication is that according to your source format you will have to create the list *before* adding values to it, and process and delete the list *after* adding values, because `(` and `)` are on the same lines as actual values.

```
Vector<String> oneOfList = null;

while(reader.ready()){
    String line=reader.readLine();

    if(line.contains("foo")){
        ...
    }
    else if (line.contains("owl:oneOf")){
        oneOfList = new Vector<String>();
    }

    if(oneOfList!=null){
        String str = line.trim();
        int a = str.indexOf("(");  // -1 if not found, OK
        int b = str.indexOf(")");
        if(b<0) b=str.length();
        oneOfList.add(str.substring(a+1,b).trim());
    }

    if (line.contains(")")){
        storeOneOf(oneOfList);
        oneOfList=null;
    }

}
```

**2)** When the oneOf header is encountered, create another small loop to read its values. A possible drawback may be that you end up with two loops iterating over the file and two calls to `reader.readLine`, which may complicate things or may not.

```
while(reader.ready()){
    String line=reader.readLine();

    if(line.contains("foo")){
        ...
    }
    else if (line.contains("owl:oneOf")){
        Vector<String> oneOfList = new Vector<String>();
        while(true){
            String str = line.trim();
            int a = str.indexOf("(");  // -1 if not found, OK
            int b = str.indexOf(")");
            int c = (b>=0) ? b : str.length();
            oneOfList.add(str.substring(a+1,c).trim());
            if(b>=0) break;
            line=reader.readLine();
        }
        storeOneOf(oneOfList);
    }

}
```

**3)** The above algorithms rely on the fact that the header, the `(` and the first value are on the same line, etc. If the source file is formatted a bit differently, the parsing will fail. A more flexible approach may be to use `StreamTokenizer` which automatically ignores whitespace and separates the text into words and stand-alone symbols:

```
StreamTokenizer tokzr=new StreamTokenizer(reader);
tokzr.wordChars(':',':');

while( tokzr.nextToken() != tokzr.TT_EOF ){
    if( tokzr.ttype==tokzr.TT_WORD && tokzr.sval.equals("foo") ){
        ...
    }
    else if ( tokzr.ttype==tokzr.TT_WORD && tokzr.sval.equals("owl:oneOf") ){
        if(tokzr.nextToken()!='(') throw new Exception("\"(\" expected");
        Vector<String> oneOfList = new Vector<String>();
        while(tokzr.nextToken() == tokzr.TT_WORD){
            oneOfList.add(tokzr.sval);
        }
        storeOneOf(oneOfList);
        if(tokzr.ttype!=')') throw new Exception("\")\" expected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have a while loop going. I really like the StreamTokenizer idea, but I will definitely try each approach and see what works best. Thank you very much for such a thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered (and rejected) existing solutions e.g: [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-input.html) ?